# Unable to create blank cell in a datagrid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using a 4 column unbound datagridview. The grid was populated with decimal numbers from an  excel worksheet. Some cells have numbers and some are left blank.

The grid is set to editmode using:

`dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter`

- If I select a cell with a number in it and replace it with another
  number, all is fine.
- If I select a blank cell and replace it with a number, all is fine.
- If I select a cell with a number in it and delete the number I get an
  error message and I cannot leave the cell until a number is entered.
- If I select a blank cell and then try to select another cell I get an
  error message and I cannot leave the cell until a number is entered.

I need the ability to have cells with numbers and cells left blank.

This is the error message when I try to leave the cell with a blank value.

> > The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
> >
> > system.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> >     ---> system.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct
> >     format.
> >
> > at System.Number.StringToNumber{string str, NumberStyles
> >     options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info,
> >     Boolean parseDecimal)
> >      at System.Number.ParseDecimal {string value, Numberstyles
> >     options, NumberFormatlnfo numfmt)
> >     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> >
> > at
> >     system.windows.Forms.Formatter.lnvokeString parse Method {obje
> >     ct value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider formatlnfo)
> >
> > at system.windows.Forms.Formatter.ParseObjectlnternal (object
> >     value, Type targetType, Type sourceType, TypeConverter
> >     targetConverter, Typeconverter sourceconverter, IForm atprovider
> >     formatlnfo, Object formatted NullValue)
> >
> > at system.windovs.Forms.Formatter.parseobject(object value,
> >     Type targetType, Type sourceType, TypeConverter
> >     targetConverter, TypeConverter sourceConverter, iForm atprovider
> >     formatlnfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object
> >     dataSourceNullValue)
> >
> > at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.ParseFormattedValueln
> >     terna(TypevalueType, Object formattedValue,
> >     DataGridViewCell.Style cellStyle, TypeConverter
> >     formatted ValueTypeConverter, Type Converter
> >     valueTypeConverter)
> >
> > at
> >     system.windows.Forms.DataGridvieCell.ParseFormattedvalue(
> >     Object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
> >     Typeconverter formattedvalueTypeconverter, Typeconverter
> >     valueTypeConverter)
> >
> > at
> >     system.windows.Forms.DataGridview.pushFormattedvalue(Data
> >     Gridviewcell& dataGridViewCurrentCell, object formattedvalue,
> >     Exception& exception)
> >
> > To replace this default dialog please handre the DataError event.`

I believe this message is associated with not being able to 'commit' the blank value to the datatable.

This is the code used to populate the datagridview:

```
Dim cb As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = XLFILENAMEANDPATH, .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"}
cb.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0; IMEX=1; HDR=Yes;")

Dim cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = cb.ConnectionString}

cn.Open()

dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" & ActName & "$B6:E" & LastEntryRow & "]", cn)

dts = New DataSet

dta.Fill(dts, "Detailtable")

DataGridView1.DataSource = dts

DataGridView1.DataMember = "Detailtable"

cn.Close()
```

I am unable to resolve the issue and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Are you creating the columns or is its auto generated?

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting. I am new to the site.

Comment: The columns are auto generated from the connection.

Comment: Are you parsing the cell value anywhere in the code using Parse.Decimal? Also provide the error stacktrace.

Comment: No. I have completely stripped the code back to the above code which populates the datagridview.

Comment: I am fairly new to VB. I do not know how to create a stack trace.

Comment: Can you post your complete code in the question. It will bring more clarity. If possible also the screen shot of the error.

Comment: You are right... somehow you will need to change all blanks to 0 values. You can do this on rowdatabound which will fire on each row being databound go through each cell in row and where necessary convert blank to 0.

Comment: I prefer not to show unused cells with zeros as it will be unsightly.

Comment: I have now included the complete exception error message above.

Answer (score 0):

When working with decimals these errors are *very often* related to culture specific problems. Most of the build in `.net` functions, where the return value is "culture dependent", uses the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to format its return value (if no other specified). Here's an example from `Decimal.Parse`:

```
Public Structure Decimal
    '...
    Public Shared Function Parse(ByVal s As String, ByVal style As NumberStyles) As Decimal
        NumberFormatInfo.ValidateParseStyleFloatingPoint(style)
        Return Number.ParseDecimal(s, style, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)
    End Function
    '...
End Structure
```

Where `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` is:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property CurrentInfo As NumberFormatInfo
    Get
        Dim currentCulture As CultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
        If Not currentCulture.m_isInherited Then
            Dim numInfo As NumberFormatInfo = currentCulture.numInfo
            If (Not numInfo Is Nothing) Then
                Return numInfo
            End If
        End If
        Return DirectCast(currentCulture.GetFormat(GetType(NumberFormatInfo)), NumberFormatInfo)
    End Get
End Property
```

You'll need to specify the proper [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the current thread.  One way is to set this in the constructor of the main form.  In Norway (where I'm from) we use `,` as a decimal separator, and not `.`. This will causes a lot of problem if I don't change the culture. So in the following example the culture is set to Norwegian:

```
Public Class Program

    Public Sub New()
         Me.InitializeComponent()
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
     End Sub

End Class
```

Here's a list of culture codes where you can find yours:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help. I eventually resolved the problem by setting the DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = ""